# nginx перенаправление запроса

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Вызываю следующий URL в браузере

```
http://192.168.0.81/API_DSC/08111989/2018
```

Срабатывает перенаправление, то есть отрабатывает как мне нужно

```
http://192.168.0.81/API_DSC/DSC.php?var1=08111989&var2=2018
```

Но вызов из консоли через `curl` дает мне 302 Found

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1/API_DSC/08111989/2018"

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот nginx конфиг с перенаправлением:

```
location /API_DSC {
    rewrite ^/API_DSC/(.*)/(.*) http://$host/API_DSC/DSC.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx тут ни при чём, нужно просто попросить `curl` следовать за переадресациями

> -L, --location      Follow redirects (H)

Comment: Действительно работает. Спасибо

Comment: А возможно ли скрыть факт перенаправление? Чтобы допустим при анализе трафика на порту 80 не было видно редиректа

Comment: да, просто делается внутренний редирект в этом же rewrite

Comment: Если можно приведите пожалуйста пример на основе моего

Comment: а в чём у вас затруднение?

Comment: Я только столкнулся с таким моментом, поэтому не совсем понимаю как сделать внутренний редирект о которым вы говорите

Comment: `rewrite ^/API_DSC/(.*)/(.*) /API_DSC/DSC.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 break;`

Comment: Идея в том что от клиента будут приходить динамические запросы вида /API_DSC/12312312/0990232  мне их нужно редиректить постоянно в одну точку входа в мой АПИ

Comment: На счет внутреннего редиректа разобрался, большое спасибо